# Query error Unknown column 'Count' in 'field list'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to sum the picks column from all the tables that have house in the table name.

```
SELECT SUM(Picks) AS A 
  FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
          FROM information_schema.TABLES 
         WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND 
               table_schema='myschema'
       ) AS T
```

This SQL statement results in the message

> Unknown column 'Picks' in 'field list'

If I query just:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME 
  FROM information_schema.TABLES 
 WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND
       table_schema='myschema'
```

It returns the expected list of tables. I have verified each of the returned tables have a count column and there are all the same data type `VARCHAR(45)`.

What am i missing?

Comment: count is a mysql reserved word

Comment: Thanks Kai, but it happens on other queries also that are not reserved words.

Comment: And if i do SELECT SUM(Picks) AS A 
  FROM GoHouse it returns the sum. GoHouse is one of the tables returned by the query of the table names.

Comment: i hope you may make mistake in field name. it may 'picks' instead of 'Picks'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT SUM(Picks) AS A 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME 
      FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND 
            table_schema='myschema'
    ) AS T
```

What you are missing is that the subquery does not have a column called `Picks`.  I mean, the following would work:

```
SELECT SUM(Picks) AS A 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 1 as Picks
      FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND 
            table_schema='myschema'
    ) AS T
```

Or this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Picks
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME
      FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND 
            table_schema='myschema'
    ) AS T
```

But in your query, `Picks` isn't defined.  Hence the error.

And, there is no such column in `information_schema.tables` either.  That leads me to think that you are quite confused.  Perhaps the column exists in the "house" tables.  However, you cannot reference the tables like that.  You may want to investigate prepared statements -- `prepare`/`execute` (see [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html)), if you really want to dynamically put a table name into a query.

Comment: This does not give an error so we may be on the right track. But it does not give the right result. It gives 13 which is the number of tables with house in the name. Picks is in the tables with the name of house. I want to sum all the picks columns from all the house tables by getting those table names from the information_schema.TABLES . SELECT SUM(Picks) AS A 
FROM (SELECT TABLE_NAME, 1 as Picks
      FROM information_schema.TABLES 
      WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%house' AND 
            table_schema='myschema'
    ) AS T

Comment: I just reread you comment " Perhaps the column exists in the "house" tables. However, you cannot reference the tables like that." That is indeed the case. Is there a different way to accomplish what i am trying to do?

Comment: @DenverDevelopers . . . Yes.  That is why I put in a reference to the documentation for prepared statements.